# Can anyone exlpain me the answer of this code in c

Tags: c, printf, operator-precedence

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int a,b,c,d;
    a=b=c=d=1;
    a=++b>1 || ++c>1 && ++d>1;
    printf("%d%d%d%d",a ,b ,c ,d);
}
```

The answer of the above code in gcc compiler is **1211**,can anyone explain me why it is so?

Comment: Read about operator precedence and *short-circuit evaluation*. But I would restrict by law to use a computer from the author of this code.

Comment: `++b` increments `b` to `2`, so b is now `> 1`, so the whole expression becomes true, so `1` is assigned to `a`. `c` and `d` remain unchanged, since there was no need to evaluate the rest of the expression.

Comment: @EugeneSh. it doesn't refer to laziness of the programming language ?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi that is not laziness but efficiency.

Comment: @WeatherVane you mean to say after checking the first condition it will not evaluate the next expression?

Comment: It skips the rest of the tests if the outcome can be known from the first test, which in this case it can. However if `++b` were not `> 1` the next test whould be done and so on. The above comment about *short-circuit evaluation* applies. So be careful about any side-effects that you need and perform them first.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 3):

here `a=++b>1 || ++c>1 && ++d>1;` this line will be executed as

```
a=((++b>1) || ((++c>1) && (++d>1))); according to precedence.
```

Associativity of `||` operation is from left to right, so `(++b>1)` will be executed first, then `b` gets incremented to `2` and left side of `||` operation will become `true`, so right side will not get executed and `c,d` remains unchanged.